# Using beanlib with grails (or another hibernate unwrapper), despite conflicting dependencies?

Tags: hibernate, spring, grails, dto

I'm trying to use some sort of hibernate object unwrapper/eager fetcher, and [beanlib](http://beanlib.sourceforge.net/) seems to do exactly what I need. However, when I try to use it within my grails `1.3.7` project, I only get the following errors:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V`

My usage is trivial:

```
Hibernate3DtoCopier replicator = new Hibernate3DtoCopier()
return replicator.deepCopy(user)
```

I've tried excluding transitive dependencies, but no matter what I seem to try, this keeps failing in various ways. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dozer does this, but only if you ignore the documentation.

```
private Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

User findUser(String userId) {
    def user = User.findByUserId(userId)
    return mapper.map(user, User.class)
}
```

The `DozerBeanSingletonWrapper` will attempt to load XML files off the classpath, while manual instantiation will not.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of Beanlib requires the java beans being replicated to have a default no-arg constructor.  The error message seems to indicate the lack of such ctor in "userService".

For more info, see FAQ(1) at:

http://beanlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/beanlib/trunk/beanlib-doc/faq.html